# Open dir from read txt

Tags: php, search, directory, dir

PHP script who open and search data from .txt is:

```
function explodeRows($data) {
  $rowsArr = explode("\n", $data);
  return $rowsArr;
}

function explodeTabs($singleLine) {
  $tabsArr = explode("\t", $singleLine);
  return $tabsArr;
}
$filename = "/txt/name.txt";
$handle   = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data     = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);
for($i=0;$i<count($rowsArr);$i++) {
  $lineDetails = explode("|",$rowsArr[$i]);
  if ($kodas == $lineDetails[2]) {
    $link3=$lineDetails[4];
    echo "";
     } }
fclose($handle);
```

It's works well, but now I transfer name.txt to another folder (folder name txt). How to make, first open this folder and search open name.txt

Comment: `if(file_exists(...))`?

Comment: `if($handle!==null)...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "txt/name.txt";
$handle   = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data     = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);
```